# Cracking this list of nested lists?

Tags: python, json, list-comprehension, nested-lists

I am trying to break apart a highly nested set of lists that contain data that I require using the code below:

```
url = 'http://www.whoscored.com/stagestatfeed/9155/stageteams/'
                    url = str(''.join(url[0:3]))
                    params = {
            'against': '0',            
            'field': '0',
            'teamId': '-1',
            'type': '8'
            }

                    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.125 Safari/537.36',
           'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
           'Host': 'www.whoscored.com',
           'Referer': 'http://www.whoscored.com/'}

                    responser = requests.get(url, params=params, headers=headers)

                    responser = json.loads(responser.text.replace("'", '"').decode('cp1252'))

                    results = defaultdict(int)
                    for match in responser: 
                        for num_events, team, events in match:
                            print "w = ", num_events
                            print "x = ", team

                            for y in events: 
                                print "y = ", events
```

A sample output from this is as so:

```
w =  13
x =  Arsenal
y =  [[[[u'goal', u'openplay', u'header', [1]], [u'goal', u'openplay', u'leftfoot', [1]], 
[u'goal', u'openplay', u'rightfoot', [3]], [u'goal', u'owngoal', u'rightfoot', [1]], [u'miss', 
u'corner', u'header', [2]], [u'miss', u'corner', u'leftfoot', [3]], [u'miss', u'corner',
u'rightfoot', [2]], [u'miss', u'crossedfreekick', u'rightfoot', [2]], [u'miss', 
u'directfreekick',
u'leftfoot', [1]], [u'miss', u'openplay', u'header', [2]], [u'miss', u'openplay', 
u'leftfoot', [16]], [u'miss', u'openplay', u'rightfoot', [23]]]]]
...
...
...


 w =  171
 x =  Queens Park Rangers
 y =  [[[[u'goal', u'openplay', u'leftfoot', [1]], [u'miss', u'corner', u'header', [5]], [u'miss',
 u'crossedfreekick', u'header', [1]], [u'miss', u'directfreekick', u'rightfoot', [2]], 
 [u'miss', u'openplay', u'header', [1]], [u'miss', u'openplay', u'leftfoot', [4]], [u'miss', 
 u'openplay', u'rightfoot', [23]], [u'miss', u'throwin', u'header', [1]]]]]
```

What I would like to get though is an output that looks like this for each team:

```
w =  13
x =  Arsenal
y = [u'goal', u'openplay', u'header', [1]]
y = [u'goal', u'openplay', u'leftfoot', [1]]
y = [u'goal', u'openplay', u'rightfoot', [3]]
...
...
...
y = [u'miss', u'openplay', u'rightfoot', [23]]
```

In this example I am iterating through each the nested list that comprises the variable `y` in my code and printing each in turn. I have tried various spins on for loops and list comprehensions for this, but not been able to get something that works.

Can someone suggest an answer?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just access using the index and the iterate over the sublist:

```
for y in events[0]:
   for sub in y:
       print ("y = ", sub)

w =  162
x =  Crystal Palace
y =  [u'goal', u'corner', u'rightfoot', [1]]
y =  [u'goal', u'crossedfreekick', u'header', [1]]
y =  [u'goal', u'openplay', u'rightfoot', [1]]
y =  [u'miss', u'corner', u'header', [6]]
y =  [u'miss', u'corner', u'rightfoot', [1]]
y =  [u'miss', u'crossedfreekick', u'header', [2]]
y =  [u'miss', u'crossedfreekick', u'leftfoot', [1]]
y =  [u'miss', u'crossedfreekick', u'rightfoot', [3]]
y =  [u'miss', u'openplay', u'header', [2]]
y =  [u'miss', u'openplay', u'leftfoot', [9]]
y =  [u'miss', u'openplay', u'rightfoot', [14]]
w =  175
x =  West Bromwich Albion
y =  [u'goal', u'corner', u'header', [2]]
y =  [u'goal', u'openplay', u'rightfoot', [3]]
y =  [u'goal', u'penalty', u'rightfoot', [1]]
y =  [u'miss', u'corner', u'header', [1]]
y =  [u'miss', u'directfreekick', u'rightfoot', [3]]
y =  [u'miss', u'openplay', u'leftfoot', [12]]
y =  [u'miss', u'openplay', u'rightfoot', [21]]
```